# É possivel a injeção de cookies por um site?

Tags: cookies

Suponha a seguinte situação:

Ao acessar um site (fórum de tecnologia), esse site injetaria cookies para que, quando eu acesse um outro site (loja que venda produtos), ele contabilizasse essa visita como origem do primeiro site (similar a um programa de sites afiliados por exemplo).

Seria possível esse tipo de manipulação de cookies por sites terceiros?

Comment: A pergunta esta fazendo somente um questionamento.

Comment: Não entendi por que ela foi encerrada também, e é uma pergunta que pode trazer respostas bem interessantes em relação a segurança de aplicações.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na prática isso não é possivel, visto que os cookies são pertencentes a um único dominio.

Isso significa que voce pode fazer um cookie funcionar em dois lugares como `teste.exemplo.com` e `teste2.exemplo.com`, mas nunca entre `teste.com` e `teste2.com` por razões de segurança.

Comment: e quem define essas razões de segurança ? :o)

Comment: A plataforma, nesse caso o browser